# Complex grid with responsive image dont't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i try to create a layout with a complex grid (for me) and in the middel a image with a max-width option. The layout should be fully responsive and i have to use Bootstrap 3.

I have the following solution right know:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:50px; display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;min-height:600px;">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background: #xccc; margin-bottom:-15px;padding:7px;">
            <p>
                Should be at top ...
            </p>            
            <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum (bottom)</p>
                <p>
                2016-2018<br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor...<br />
                123<br /><br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600.png/09f/fff" class="img-responsive center-block" id="img" style="max-width:600px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background: #ccc;">
            <p>
                Should be at top ...
            </p>
            <p>
                Schould be at bottom <br />
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/squarebutton/09f/fff" class="img-responsive" style="width:70px;float:left;margin-right:5px;" />
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/squarebutton/09f/fff" class="img-responsive" style="width:70px;" />
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1m6gw2dt/

This works only at desktop but if i resize the window the columns doesn't reorder for the mobilde view. Also the image reacts not to the responsive option.

And i don't know if my code example has not the best structure for my requirements?

**Edit**
This is just an experiment, it does not have to be < p >. The result Mobile should be a normal behavior that the left area appears first, then the picture and at the end the right area.

**Edit 2**
To clarify, I have inserted a picture
[image]

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: If what you are attempting to do is putting the second p "should be at the top", at the top of the page, I don't even think it's possible. But maybe I am misunderstanding. Could you provide like a drawing/wireframing or even an integration of how it should look on mobile ?

Comment: This is just an experiment, it does not have to be <p>. The result at mobile should be a normal behavior that the left area appears first, then the picture and at the end the right area.

Comment: hello, when you use flex, no need to use absolute. mind margin also . example http://jsfiddle.net/1m6gw2dt/1/  you can use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ as a reminder or a tutorial ;)

Comment: @Paulie_D i attached an image.

Comment: Hello. I'm still not sure I follow even with the image. You might want to look at the push pull classes in Bootstrap though if you want to order to change on mobile. Build mobile 1st and reorder when the screen is bigger.

Comment: @G-Cyr hey thank you very much. this works! ;o)

Comment: @SpaceBeers thank you, the solution from G-Cyr works ;o)

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry. Just did a flexbox answer. Feel free to ignore.

Comment: @G-Cyr I can delete the flexbox answer if you want the points.

Comment: @SpaceBeers its okay, i only meant to comment. i saw bootstrap 3 but flex also in iline style. bootstrap4 would have done the job ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you need but if you want to push to the top and the bottom then flexbox is the way to go.

https://jsbin.com/bijekaqoji/edit?html,css,js,output

`<div class="big-boy-box">
    <p>I'm at the top</p>
    <p>I'm at the bottom</p>
  </div>`

`.big-boy-box {
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}`

You can remove this through media queries as and when you want to.